# jQuery: count how many list items storing that value into a variable and passing it as text into a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working with an Accordion- I have a list inside the accordion with an class of area-list  I want to count how many list items exist inside this list, store that number into a variable. I have a span I want to update with the count of area-list. I have to do this on multiple accordions. Thanks in advance.

```
 <ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
        <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
        <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accounting (<span class="counter">1000</span>)</a>
        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>

    <ul class="no-bullet area-list">
      <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
      <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
      <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
    </ul>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


<ul class="accordion" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
        <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
<a href="#" class="accordion-title">Accounting 2 (<span 
    class="counter">1000</span>)</a>    
<div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>

      <ul class="no-bullet area-list">
               <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
          <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
          <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
          <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
      <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
      <li><a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a></li>
    </ul>

        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

<script>

function getCounter(){
var count = $("#myList li").length;
$("span.counter").text(count);

}

getCounter();

</script>
```

Comment: Did you forget to include the span element?

Comment: there's a span with a class of counter in here.

Comment: I just added all your code along with a `<span class="counter"></span>` to a JSFiddle and it appears to work just fine?

Comment: sorry, this was an old version of this issue. I need to do this on multiple accordions.

Comment: So do you want to have a count for each accordion or consolidate these into one?

Comment: I want the count for each individual accordion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I figured it out, I needed to write this to be more vague so I could use it on multiple instances of the accordion. Thanks Everyone!

 function getCounter(){
      var count = $(this).find(".area-list").children('li').length;
      $(this).find("span.counter").text(count);
  }

  $(".accordion").each(getCounter);
```

Comment: Ah, well it seems we ended up with the same answer. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

This should sum up the elements of each accordion.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".accordion").each(function() {
    var count = $(this).find(".area-list").children("li").length;
    $(this).find(".counter").text(count);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion="" data-allow-all-closed="true">
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item="">
    <a class="accordion-title" href="#">Accounting (<span class="counter">1000</span>)</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content="">
      <ul class="no-bullet area-list">
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul class="accordion" data-accordion="" data-allow-all-closed="true">
  <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item="">
    <a class="accordion-title" href="#">Accounting 2 (<span class="counter">1000</span>)</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content="">
      <ul class="no-bullet area-list">
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a class="naming" href="#">Benny Goodman</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `children()` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/children/)).

```
function getCounter(){
    var count = $("#myList").children('li').length;
    $("span.counter").text(count);
}
```